# XDocument get and set values in XML nodes

Tags: c#, xml

I have this XML

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>`
`<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">`
  `<S:Header>`
    `<wss:Security xmlns:wss="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">`
      `<wss:UsernameToken>`
        `<wss:Username>username</wss:Username>`
        `<wss:Password>password</wss:Password>`
        `<wss:Nonce></wss:Nonce>`
        `<wss:Created></wss:Created>`
      `</wss:UsernameToken>`
    `</wss:Security>`
  `</S:Header>`
  `<S:Body>`
      `<TaxRegistrationNumber>213213123</TaxRegistrationNumber>`
      `<CompanyName>sadsadasd</CompanyName>`
  `</S:Body>`
`</S:Envelope>`


I want to accesses to the value of `<wss:Username>` and set a value in `<wss:Nonce>` node.

I already try 3 ways to get value of `<wss:Username>` on C# project:

First:
`XDocument xmlFile = XDocument.Load(xmlpathfile);`
`XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());`
`ns.AddNamespace("wss", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext/");`
`XElement UserFinanc = xmlFile.XPathSelectElement("wss:Security/wss:UsernameToken/wss:Username", ns);`

Second:
`XDocument xmlFile = XDocument.Load(xmlpathfile);`
`XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());`
`var element = xmlFile.Descendants(wss + "Security").Descendants(wss + "UsernameToken").Where(x => x.Descendants(wss + "Username").Any(y => y.Value != "")).First().Element(wss + "UsernameToken");`
`if (element != null)`
`MessageBox.Show(element.Element(wss + "Username").Value).Value);`
Third:
`string grandChild = (string) (from el in xmlFile.Descendants(wss + "Username")  select el).First();`
`MsgBox.Show(grandChild);`
I always have similar errors like 'The sequence contains no elements'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: You need to use `XNamespace`.

Comment: @SLaks like that? `XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());`<br>
`ns.AddNamespace("wss", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext/");`<br> I already use it

Comment: No; you need to use `XNamespace`, which is part of the new XLINQ API.  The `Xml*` classes are from an older API which is not relevant.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-create-a-document-with-namespaces-linq-to-xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first attempt is almost right. There are a couple things missing:

1. The namespace defined in code must be an **exact** match to the one in the xml. In your case the namespace in code has an extra trailing slash. It should be `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext`.
2. The XPath expression should be `//wss:Security/wss:UsernameToken/wss:Username`. The leading slashes basically mean "look for this node anywhere". Alternatively, you could write out the whole path begining with `<S:Envelope>`. You would need to add the soap envelope namespace to your code as well.